# Why does using an non-inlined It.IsAny<T> in Moq not work correctly?

Tags: c#, moq

Assigning `It.IsAny<T>()` to a variable for use in a `Setup` on a mocked object does not work as expected: the test shown below fails.

However, if I inline the `anyString` variable the test passes. What's going on here?

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyService(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string UseTheDependency(string input)
    {
        return _dependency.GetValue(input);
    }
}

public interface IDependency
{
    string GetValue(string input);
}

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestTheTestClass()
    {
        var mockDependency = new Mock<IDependency>();
        var anyString = It.IsAny<string>();
        mockDependency.Setup(x => x.GetValue(anyString)).Returns("expected value");
        var service = new MyService(mockDependency.Object);
        var result = service.UseTheDependency("something random");
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("expected value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `Setup` method takes a Linq Expression (`Expression<Func<IDependency, string>>`) as a parameter, not a delegate (`Func<IDependency, string>`). It allows Moq to inspect the abstract syntax tree to know what call is being configured. If you use a variable declared outside the expression, Moq doesn't know that you used `It.IsAny`, it just sees a `null` (technically, it sees an access to the field `anyString` of the object that encapsulates the captured local variables, and that field just contains `null`).

---

EDIT: I wrote this answer a long time ago, and I now realize it was partly incorrect. I've been a maintainer of [FakeItEasy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/) (another mocking library) for many years, and it uses an approch similar to Moq's, so now I have a better understanding of it...

It's not true that `It.IsAny` should never executed; it *is* executed, and produces an argument constraint. But that constraint is only captured when evaluating the call expression in `Setup`, when Moq has the context for that constraint. If you just call `It.IsAny` outside the call to `Setup`, when there is no context for it, the produced constraint isn't captured, and is just discarded.

Comment: Thanks, I could have seen that had I inspected the types more closely. But its a pity the compiler lets you do it at all.

Comment: @Nick, I don't see how the compiler could detect it. The code with the local variable is perfectly legal, it's just not how Moq should be used. And the compiler doesn't know how Moq is supposed to be used... What could be done in Moq, though, is to throw an exception when `It.IsAny` is executed, because it shouldn't be executed. And the exception could explain what's wrong.